# Where should the authorization logic go in an api based application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, security, authorization, abac

I have a brand new Rails api based application, where i need to implement authorization.

Overall Architecture:

`React frontend -> Rails API layer -> Rails model/server layer`

While exploring different approaches, I have got a confusion.

1. Should we put the authorization logic in API layer or Service layer?
2. **API Layer Approach:**   We will build some authorization middleware that will sit between our front end and API layer and all our api calls will be routed thorough the authorization middleware to check if the user is allowed to call that parituclar api.
3. **Service Layer:** All the authorization check will go to service layer and we will have check before every db operation if the user is allowed to do so. (Using `cancancan / pundit`) and if the user is not allowed throw the error message to API layer.

It would be a great help, if someone could suggest based on their experience.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Outside the app - always externalize authorization. Decouple your authorization logic from your business logic.

## Longer answer

Since the beginning of SOA (service-oriented architecture), API architectures and now microservices, the trend has been towards breaking down application silos and designing systems in such a way you can reuse common functionality. For instance, you use a central authentication service (you wouldn't, I hope, implement your own authentication scheme) and a central logging mechanism.

The same applies to authorization. There is something called [externalized authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Externalized_Authorization) which promotes:

- **decoupling** authorization logic from the application. Many dev frameworks already do that (Spring Security, Microsoft Claims, Ruby CanCanCan...)
- **centralizing** authorization logic into a single point of management.
- expressing authorization logic as human-readable **policies**. This means you can write policies such as

  - Doctors can view the medical records of patients they have a relationship with
- using **attributes** to define these policies: this is called attribute-based access control (ABAC). It is the de factor authorization model for new app developments (such as API). NIST published an [excellent report](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/) on the topic in 2013.

## Architecture

ABAC promotes the following architecture and flow (more [details here](https://www.axiomatics.com/blog/xacml-reference-architecture/))

- Policy Enforcement Point
- Policy Decision Point
- Policy Information Point
- Policy Administration Point

[image: XACML & ABAC Architecture - Axiomatics]

## ABAC Implementation: XACML & ALFA

### Generic approaches

There are 2 standards that implement ABAC today. XACML provides both a language and an architecture (see above). ALFA provides a [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)).

### ABAC in Ruby

Check out this project: [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Comment: Off course I can use cancancan gem in the service layer for authorization.
But let's say there is an api  to approve a review request and only super admins can do that. So if an admin calls the same api, Should i through the error before they can call the api using some middleware authorization api OR I should through the error from the service layer to api layer and api will return the same to view layer?

Comment: Defense in depth is your best approach; defend early

Comment: @DavidBrossard How do you actually implement ABAC in Microservices as a centralized service? Specifically, how does a common authorization service provide the PIP module for all the microservices? How can a common authz service know about all the attributes of all the entities managed by all the microservices? It looks like for Microservices ABAC cannot be centralized (except for may be PAP). OTOH if you have insights of actually doing a centralized ABAC for microservices, I would love to learn about it.