# Distributed or Central Authorisation in Django Microservices

Tags: django, authorization, jwt, microservices

I'm building a Django rest framework based service which has some complicated permissions. So far, my microservices stack looks like this:

- /auth/ JWT authentication service
- /users/ - adding users, adding them to different services
- /new-service/ - needs authorization

Users database is shared by `auth` and `users` read-only, and read/write respectively. `new-service` has no access to this database but the challenges consist of:

- user can be in multiple groups specific to that service
- user could have read-only access to one item in one of the groups
- user could be allowed to create new users with access to one of the groups
- users have different roles in the service, but we still need to allow for access like the read-only one listed

Groups are used not to manage users, but to provide access to things. Like GitLab groups provide access to GitLab projects.

If I put all the permissions in the `users` service, my new service has to talk to that one and it will get chatty. It seems like there has to be a data divide, but I'm not sure exactly where to put it. Conversely, should the django-rest-framework service even have a shadow entry of the user account in it's db? Advice appreciated. I'm feeling like I'm having a slow day.

Comment: Just so I'm clear - I do not mean authentication.

Comment: Use attribute based access control or XACML. It does just what you need

Comment: @DavidBrossard That's a lot of stuff to put in a JWT token's scope attribute.  Also, that'll potentially involve the microservice having to call the user's service to check their permissions on each request.

Comment: You wouldn't put it as scopes. Policies are not meant to be distributed around. They are meant to drive the authZ. They could be used to automatically generate scopes. Or you could keep scopes simple i.e. just user attributes and then have policies on the SP side that are used to determine what a user can do given the scopes they have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should the authorization logic go in an api based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396691/where-should-the-authorization-logic-go-in-an-api-based-application)

Comment: See this answer for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396691/where-should-the-authorization-logic-go-in-an-api-based-application

Comment: I've been focusing on using RBAC as it is something that I know, but I am starting to see the limitations. XACML looks way too complicated.

Comment: What makes you think it's complicated? It's much easier than RBAC IMHO

Comment: Okay, so if I wasn't using scopes, the resource server would have to ask the authZ service if the user has the matching required permissions then? This is an extra call back every time the api is hit